# Java Jsoup Error Handling

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I have the following method:

```
public Article buildArticle(SNSpecific specific, String urlToScrape) throws IOException {


        Document page = Jsoup.connect(urlToScrape).timeout(10*1000).get();

        Article a = new Article();
        a.setWebsite("http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/");
        a.setUrl(urlToScrape);
        a.setTitle(page.select(specific.getTitleSelector()).text());
        a.setDiscoveryTime(page.select(specific.getDateAndTimeSelector()).text());

        if(isPdfPage(urlToScrape))
        {
            Elements e = page.select("div.indepth-content > div.content > ul.indepth-list a");

            a.setText(page.select("div.readmoreSummary").text() + "For full article: " +
                    e.first().attr("href"));
        }else {
            a.setText(page.select(specific.getContentSelector()).text());
        }
        return a;
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes it cannot connect to the `urlToScrape` even I changed the timeout, and I dont want to wait too long for a page and thats why I am looking for an alternative solution except the `timeout()` method, what could be another approach to handle this problem?(I have about 200 pages to scrape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what could be another approach to handle this problem?(I have about 200 pages to scrape).

I can see two options:

- Give server some rest between two requests.
  *Between two fetches make a random pause between 2000 ms and 5000 ms*
- Use a proxy
  *If you don't want to make pauses between two fetches*

Comment: I have used the 1st option and it works perfectly ! :)

Comment: @imoteb It's not reflected in my  answer but you can make the pause random between 2000 ms and 5000 ms.

Comment: I actually put some delay as you mentioned and if it throws some exception again I am putting the link in a queue to try again later